# folder structure of react native app without redux

Tags: react-native

I'm struggling with folder structure of my react native app.
My app is a simple form app and doesn't use redux.
My folder structure is below:

```
App.js
index.js
package.json
```

Yes, I didn't add any files...
I searched on google, but I found only folder structure with redux.
I wrote almost all my code in App.js, but I think it is becoming complex a bit.
I want to know where to move logics from App.js.

My App.js is like this:

```
some import codes here

export default class App extends Component{
  super()
  this.state={//init state}

  initState(){
    //initialize state
    //this is called when the submit button is pushed
  }

  onPress(){
    //this function is called when the submit button is pushed
  }

 render(){
   return(
     //a lot of inputs here like id, name, email, date, comment...
     //I think I can divide these inputs as components
   )
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   //style sheets here
 })
}
```

I want to know

- Where to put my "onPress" or "initState" or some other functions.
- How to divide simple form inputs to components
- Whether I can remove stylesheets from App.js or not and where to put them

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully, this will help you to organize you project structure. https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/organizing-a-react-native-project-9514dfadaa0

Comment: I have a similar structure in flutter, though I used the same in quite a number of  react and react native projects. https://github.com/jinxac/flutter-folder-structure. Maybe can help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on several apps with different different folder structure with or without redux. But I found this folder structure very helpful.This structure also helps in large scale application as well for small scale applications.

Fractal — A react app structure for infinite scale

https://hackernoon.com/fractal-a-react-app-structure-for-infinite-scale-4dab943092af

Comment: I liked the way this is structured, even i used this for few of my projects. I really liked https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-better-organize-your-react-applications-2fd3ea1920f1  also though. Do give it a read.